# How to set default data of missing date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
[DEPT_NAME]     [EMP_NAME]              [DESIGNATION]      [01-03-2013] [02-03-2013]    [03-03-2013]    [04-03-2013]    [05-03-2013]    [07-03-2013]
EMaint          CHAWAN ASHOK UKHARDU    ITI-Jr. Technician     NULL        NULL           0,0,0,0            NULL        0,0,0,0         0,0,0,0
```

The above result how to set default data of missing date(06-03-2013).

Please help me.

Comment: Please consider describing your situation in more details.

Comment: pls do edit neatly use `{}` to format ! right now its unclear !

Comment: hi, in my table i have column like "day", in that daily we are updating attendence and weekoff we are not updating. so when get a report in month wise that week off date is missing. but i have to show that date also in reoport

Comment: `update table set column='06-03-2013' where column=NULL` this is a update statement you could use !

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL function in your select query like this:

```
SELECT ..., ISNULL( Col1, '01-03-2013' ), ... FROM ...
```